# I am trying to create a binary variable in R on two conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, binary-data

I created two variables "score_diff" and "seed_diff", I would like to create a binary variable which is defined by if the score_diff is <0 and if the seed_diff is greater than 5.

```
df$score_diff <- df$score1- df$score2
df$seed_diff <- df$seed1- df$seed2
```

I tried this, however, it didn't work, I am new to this so bear with me:

```
df$upset <- ifelse(df$score_diff<0 & df$seed_diff>5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work, cos you only set the condition, and not what should happen in case the condition is TRUE or FALSE. So, the second argument `1`, says that in case the condition is TRUE, the value is 1; and the third argument specifies what should happen if the condition is FALSE. Simplified: `ifelse(test, yes, no)`.

```
df$upset <- ifelse(df$score_diff<0 & df$seed_diff>5, 1, 0)
```

Comment: You should explain why this works and the question's code doesn't. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, your code only specifies the "test" (`df$score_diff < 0 & df$seed_diff > 5`) part of an `ifelse` statement. If you want to convert it to an `integer` with values `0,1` you can use `as.integer`.

```r
df$upset <- as.integer(df$score_diff < 0 & df$seed_diff > 5)
```

Comment: You should explain why this answers the question. Code only answers are frowned upon.